# How to print out a 2D vector of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing a program which includes a 2D vector of objects:

```
class Obj{
public:
    int x;
    string y;
};

vector<Obj> a(100);

vector< vector<Obj> > b(10);
```

I've stored some values of vector a in vector b.

I get an error when I try to print it out like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<b[i].size(); j++)
      cout << b[i][j];
    cout << endl;
}
```

error info:

> D:\main.cpp:91: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka Obj}')
>          cout << b[i][j];
>               ^

Comment: There is no such thing as a 2D vector of objects. You have a vector of vectors of objects.

Comment: How would you print the object if it weren't inside a "2D vector"? Being inside a vector doesn't magically transform a type.

Comment: Learn more about [range `for` loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: In future, please provide a complete program all in one piece. [MCVE]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is not related to vectors, it is related to sending object(s) of some user defined type `Obj` to the standard output. When you send an object to the output stream using the [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) as you do with:

```
cout << b[i][j];
```

the stream does not know what to do with it as none of the [12 overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) accepts a user defined type `Obj`. You need to overload the `operator<<` for your class `Obj`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Obj& obj) {
    os << obj.x  << ' ' << obj.y;
    return os;
}
```

or even a vector of `Obj`s:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<Obj>& vec) {
    for (auto& el : vec) {
        os << el.x << ' ' << el.y << "  ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

For more info on the subject check out this SO post:
[What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421708)

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with your vectors.

You are trying to print an `Obj`, but you didn't tell your computer how you would like it to do that.

Either print `b[i][j].x` and `b[i][j].y` individually, or overload `operator<<` for `Obj`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `cout::operator<<` that takes a `class Obj` as a right hand side. You could define one. Simplest solution is to send `x` and `y` to `cout` separately. But use range-based for-loops!

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Obj {
public:
    int x;
    string y;
};

vector<vector<Obj>> b(10);

void store_some_values_in_b() {
    for (auto& row : b) {
        row.resize(10);
        for (auto& val : row) {
            val.x = 42; val.y = " (Ans.) ";
        }
    }
}

int main() { 

    store_some_values_in_b();

    for (auto row: b) {
        for (auto val : row) {
            cout << val.x << " " << val.y;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like below

```
for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<b[i].size(); j++)
        cout << "(" << b[i][j].x << ", " << b[i][j].y << ") ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation.